# Numpy- Deep Learning, Training Examples

Tags: numpy, machine-learning

Silly Question, I am going through the third week of Andrew Ng's newest Deep learning course, and getting stuck at a fairly simple Numpy function ( i think? ).

The exercise is to find How many training examples, m , we have.

Any idea what the Numpy function is to find out about the size of a preloaded training example.

Thanks!

```
shape_X = X.shape
shape_Y = Y.shape
m = ?


print ('The shape of X is: ' + str(shape_X))
print ('The shape of Y is: ' + str(shape_Y))
print ('I have m = %d training examples!' % (m))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It depends** on what kind of storage-approach you use.

Most python-based tools use the `[n_samples, n_features]` approach where the first dimension is the sample-dimension, the second dimension is the feature-dimension (like in scikit-learn and co.). Alternatively expressed: samples are rows and features are columns.

So:

```
#     feature  1 2 3 4
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4], # first sample
              [2,3,4,5], # second sample
              [3,4,5,6]
             ])
```

is a training-set of 3 samples with 4 features each.

The sizes M,N (again: interpretation might be different for others) you can get with:

```
M, N = x.shape
```

because numpy's first dimension are rows, numpy's second dimension are columns [like in matrix-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)).

For the above example, the target-array is of shape `(M) = n_samples`.

Comment: that's an awesome explanation! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you want to find the number of training examples or the size of an array, you can use

```
m = X.size
```

This will give you the size or the total number of the examples. In this case, it would be 400. 
The above method is also correct but not the optimal method to find the size since, in large datasets, the values could be large and while python easily handles large values, it is not advisable to utilize extra unneeded space.

Or a better way of doing the above scenario is

```
m=X.shape[1]
```